# Using rewhere on joined conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this code:

```
class Meeting
  has_many :attendees, class_name: 'MeetingsUsers', autosave: true

  scope :x, -> { Meeting.where(x:13) }
  scope :y, -> { Meeting.where('x':13) }
  scope :z, -> { Meeting.joins(:attendees).where('meetings_users.user_id': 123)}
end
```

Rewhere works in these situations:
`Meeting.x.to_sql
Meeting.x.rewhere(x: 1234).to_sql 
Meeting.y.to_sql
Meeting.y.rewhere('x': 1234).to_sql`

But in this case it doesn't:

`Meeting.z.to_sql`

The resulting SQL is this one:
`"SELECT \"meetings\".* FROM \"meetings\" INNER JOIN \"meetings_users\" ON \"meetings_users\".\"meeting_id\" = \"meetings\".\"id\" AND \"meetings_users\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL WHERE \"meetings\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL AND \"meetings_users\".\"user_id\" = 123"`

With rewhere:

`Meeting.z.rewhere('meetings_users.user_id': 1234).to_sql`

The resulting SQL is this one:
`"SELECT \"meetings\".* FROM \"meetings\" INNER JOIN \"meetings_users\" ON \"meetings_users\".\"meeting_id\" = \"meetings\".\"id\" AND \"meetings_users\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL WHERE \"meetings\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL AND \"meetings_users\".\"user_id\" = 123 AND \"meetings_users\".\"user_id\" = 1234"`

As you can see there are two conditional on the same field:

`"meetings_users\".\"user_id\" = 123 AND \"meetings_users\".\"user_id\" = 1234"`

So rewhere didn't had effect by some mysterious reason...

Comment: Unfortunately It won't work out I debugged it. In the query_methods.rb line 914 "the subrelation.name == target_value" should be something like rel.left.relation.name + "." + rel.left.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really an ActiveRecord bug, you can see on:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L650

That rewhere just send the keys of the first hash object, that latter on are consider as 'columns to be removed from from where caluse'.

You can check the end of the process here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/where_clause.rb#L135

They have changed this last method in rails 5.0.2, but since the other ones haven't been changed, the behavior of rewhere is still the same.

You are only able to work this around doing:

```
class Meeting
  has_many :attendees, class_name: 'MeetingsUsers', autosave: true

  scope :x, -> { Meeting.where(x:13) }
  scope :y, -> { Meeting.where('x':13) }
  scope :z, -> { Meeting.joins(:attendees).where(meetings_users: {user_id: 123})}
end

query = Meeting.z
query.where_clause = query.where_clause.except('user_id')
query.where(meetings_users: {user_id: 1234})
```

Notice that this only works if you are using the where with hash, because using as string ll cause an ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation error.